# Warning: Array to string conversion in /app/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php while saving the payment information

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, place-order

Warning: Array to string conversion in /app/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php while saving the payment information on rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information in checkout page payment method selection.

> A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again.

above error thrown while saving the payment information.